# How can I add the values of some variables given in one data set by the nature of the variables given in another data sets?

Tags: dataset

Please consider two data sets dat1 and dat2 in the following format.

```
Dat1:

 x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
 1    3   8   2  10
 2   12   2   9   6
```

and Dat2:

```
var     type
x1    discrete
x2     contns
x3    discrete
x4     discrete 
x5     contns
```

I want to add the values of the variables in dat1 by the nature from dat2. In other words, I want to have variables adding values from from dat1  XX=x1+x3+x4 and YY=x2+x5. Can you please suggest me how can I do it in R. Actually, I have few more categories or types of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
uniquetypes<-unique(Dat2$type)
result<-sapply(uniquetypes, function(curtype){
  rowSums(Dat1[, Dat2$type==curtype])
})
```

If you have other columns in Dat1, you may need a bit of editing (current code is index based, not based on the name of the column).

Comment: Sorry, had a few glitches. New code should work.

Comment: I needed to modify the code but the idea was same. Thanks.